# Powershell string to array

Tags: arrays, string, loops, powershell

In Powershell how would I convert a string with a varying length of characters to an array formatted to a specific number of characters per item? Example using 10 characters per item in the array:

```
string: 012345678901234567890123456789

array:

0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
```

So the first item in the array would be the first 10 characters of the string, the second item the next 10, and so on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$num = '012345678901234567890123456789123' #Lenght is 33
#$num = '012345678901234567890123456789' #Lenght is 30
$split = 10
$len = $num.Length

$repeat=[Math]::Floor($len/$split)

for($i=0;$i-lt$repeat;$i++){
    #$num[($i*$split)..($i*$split+$split-1)]
    Write-Output (($num[($i*$split)..($i*$split+$split-1)]) -join '')
}
if($remainder=$len%$split){
    #$num[($len-$remainder)..($len-1)]
    Write-Output (($num[($len-$remainder)..($len-1)]) -join '')
}
```

Hope this helps

Even Better make it into a resuable function, like this:

```
function Split-ByLength{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Splits string up by Split length.

    .DESCRIPTION
    Convert a string with a varying length of characters to an array formatted to a specific number of characters per item.

    .EXAMPLE
    Split-ByLength '012345678901234567890123456789123' -Split 10

    0123456789
    0123456789
    0123456789
    123

    .LINK
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171531/powershell-string-to-array/17173367#17173367
    #>

    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]]$InputObject,

        [int]$Split=10
    )
    begin{}
    process{
        foreach($string in $InputObject){
            $len = $string.Length

            $repeat=[Math]::Floor($len/$Split)

            for($i=0;$i-lt$repeat;$i++){
                #Write-Output ($string[($i*$Split)..($i*$Split+$Split-1)])
                Write-Output $string.Substring($i*$Split,$Split)
            }
            if($remainder=$len%$split){
                #Write-Output ($string[($len-$remainder)..($len-1)])
                Write-Output $string.Substring($len-$remainder)
            }
        }        
    }
    end{}
}

$num1 = '012345678901234567890123456789' #Lenght is 30
$num2 = '012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789123123' #Lenght is 33

Split-ByLength -InputObject $num2 -Split 10
```

Comment: I like this method because it handles the remainder. It does need a -join "" method applied to the output though to recreate the string elements. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot you were using strings so it would be better to use `$a.substring(start,length)`.

Comment: i just get one item per line... not 10

Comment: @mpgn The even better part works. I've "improved" the first part. Simply added a `-join` to the line.

Comment: Thanks!  I came from a google search but this was super helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do that:

```
$a = '012345678901234567890123456789'

if($a.length % 10)
{
    for($i=0; $i -lt $a.length; $i+=10)
    {
        $a.Substring($i,10)    
    }
}
else
{
    "String length must devide in 10 without a remainder"
}
```

Another way:

```
if($a.length % 10)
{
    0..2 | Foreach {$a.Substring(($_*10),10)}
}
else
{
    "String length must devide in 10 without a remainder"
}
```